# SQL Server 2012 stored procedure execution times vary wildly

Tags: caching, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a simple stored procedure that accepts only 2 parameters; the first is always supplied and the second is always null by observation, and is there only so as not to break the call from the application.  There is a scheduled SQL Agent task that stores the stored procedure execution statistics, then clears the cached plans weekly.  There are also nightly scheduled jobs to rebuild or reorganize indexes using Ola Hallegren's maintenance procedures using the default parameters.

Recently, following the clearing of the cache the stored procedure execution time sometimes jumps from its normal, 2-15 ms to 120,000 ms.  Calling sp_recompile on the stored procedure drops the execution time back to normal.  All the wait times are CPU/Memory according to SolarWinds DPA (formerly Ignite).

Running Profiler, I can copy the execution call made by the web apps, paste it into SSMS running on my laptop, and get execution times in the normal MS ranges, whereas the Duration from the apps according to Profiler is wildly higher.  Calls that take 2 minutes from the app will complete in < 10 milliseconds on my laptop within seconds of the completion of the call from the app.

I would expect both executions to use the same same cached plan and result in the same performance, but that obviously is not the case, and since I have never seen a non-null value for the second parameter, I don't think it's an oddball call that includes it that could be caching a bad plan.

The entire stored procedure code follows.  Its sole purpose is to return a 3-row result set indicating if a particular mall has any current content of types 1 through 3.

```
 dbo.usp_s_mall_has_rsc_content
    @mall_id        INT,
    @base_tenant_id INT = NULL
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT  1 AS showcase_item_type_id,
        IIF(EXISTS( SELECT  *
                    FROM    dbo.content_stream_owner AS cso
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream_data AS csd ON csd.content_stream_data_id = cso.content_stream_data_id
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream AS cs ON cs.content_stream_id = csd.content_stream_id
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream_logins AS csl
                                ON (csl.mall_id = cso.mall_id OR csl.base_tenant_id = cso.base_tenant_id)
                    WHERE   cso.mall_id = @mall_id
                            AND (@base_tenant_id IS NULL OR cso.base_tenant_id = @base_tenant_id)
                            AND csd.content_stream_id = 1
                            AND csd.end_dt > SYSDATETIME()
                            AND csd.hidden_flags = 0
                            AND cs.is_active = 1
                            AND csl.is_active = 1), 1, 0) AS has_content
UNION
SELECT  2 , IIF(EXISTS( SELECT  *
                    FROM    dbo.content_stream_owner AS cso
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream_data AS csd ON csd.content_stream_data_id = cso.content_stream_data_id
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream AS cs ON cs.content_stream_id = csd.content_stream_id
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream_logins AS csl
                                ON (csl.mall_id = cso.mall_id OR csl.base_tenant_id = cso.base_tenant_id)
                    WHERE   cso.mall_id = @mall_id
                            AND (@base_tenant_id IS NULL OR cso.base_tenant_id = @base_tenant_id)
                            AND csd.content_stream_id = 2
                            AND csd.end_dt > SYSDATETIME()
                            AND csd.hidden_flags = 0
                            AND cs.is_active = 1
                            AND csl.is_active = 1), 1, 0)
UNION
SELECT  3 , IIF(EXISTS( SELECT  *
                    FROM    dbo.content_stream_owner AS cso
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream_data AS csd ON csd.content_stream_data_id = cso.content_stream_data_id
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream AS cs ON cs.content_stream_id = csd.content_stream_id
                            JOIN dbo.content_stream_logins AS csl
                                ON (csl.mall_id = cso.mall_id OR csl.base_tenant_id = cso.base_tenant_id)
                    WHERE   cso.mall_id = @mall_id
                            AND (@base_tenant_id IS NULL OR cso.base_tenant_id = @base_tenant_id)
                            AND csd.content_stream_id = 3
                            AND csd.end_dt > SYSDATETIME()
                            AND csd.hidden_flags = 0
                            AND cs.is_active = 1
                            AND csl.is_active = 1), 1, 0);
```

Comment: When the performance changes from one time to another it is mostly due to a difference in execution plan that has been chosen by SQL. Recheck your indexes, run the query with actual execution plan tracing to see if the indexes are hit right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the store procedure recompile everytime?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_s_mall_has_rsc_content
    @mall_id        INT,
    @base_tenant_id INT = NULL
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
...
```

I have seen this problem with some of my stored procedure. You have queries nested inside `IIF(...)`. `IIF` expects only scalar parameters so somehow SQL Server thinks all the tables involved only give 1 row to the `JOIN` and use the inefficient `LOOP JOIN`. It blows up as soon as the tables return a few thousand rows each to participate in the join.